# Save queried result into database

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, terms, wpdb, meta-value

in multi author website when author publish post , he/her can give star rating to his/her own post. and I can display average rating for every taxonomy term using this formula:

`AVERAGE RATING=TOTAL STAR RATING SUM / TOTAL POST COUNT IN CURRENT TAXONOMY TERM ARCHIVE.`

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span  id=stars></span>
<?php
$term_slug = get_queried_object()->slug;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page'   => -1,    // Number of posts per page
  'post_type'     => array('A-CPT','B-CPT'),  // Custom Post Types
  'tax_query'     => array(
              array(
                'taxonomy' => 'MY-TAXONOMY-SLUG-NAME',  //Custom Taxonomy Name 
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 
                   $term_slug
                )
              )
            )
  );
  
$new = new WP_Query( $args );
 $count = $new->post_count;  // Total post count
if ( have_posts() ) while ($new->have_posts()) : $new->the_post(); ?>
  <?php
$post_id = get_the_ID();
  $post_rating = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ratings_3421372395', true ); // getting rating metavalues from posts
?>
<?php
if (!empty($post_rating)){
        $reviewsNum += $post_rating;
    }
?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php
$averagerating = $reviewsNum / $count; ?> 
<?php  //echo $count; ?>
<?php // echo $reviewsNum; ?>


<script>
    document.getElementById("stars").innerHTML = getStars(<?php echo  $averagerating; 
?>);

function getStars(rating) {

  // Round to nearest half
  rating = Math.round(rating * 2) / 2;
  let output = [];

  // Append all the filled whole stars
  for (var i = rating; i >= 1; i--)
    output.push('<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px; color: green;"></i> ');

  // If there is a half a star, append it
  if (i == .5) output.push('<i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px; color: green;"></i> ');

  // Fill the empty stars
  for (let i = (5 - rating); i >= 1; i--)
    output.push('<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px; color: green;"></i> ');

  return output.join('');

}
</script>
```

But I also need to save average rating result into db for current taxonomy term.  thatswhy i created custom meta field for taxonomy terms ( Example: avareage_star_rating) . But how can I save average rating in db automaticly

Comment: Your code appears to be incomplete, there is no code in your question to send the new rating back to the server that can be used to calculate and update the average. Doing it in javascript means anybody could change the average and abuse the system. This has to be done server side in PHP.

Comment: average rating calculated with php. javascript is used to display output value as stars

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is then, can you describe using different words? Are you trying to avoid calculating the average by saving it? Can't you do that when a post is saved?

Comment: Example: I display total post count in taxonomy term archive. Then how can I save this result in database of this taxonomy term custom meta field

Comment: So it's specifically, how to save term meta? If so, is `update_term_meta` the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save term meta using `update_term_meta`:

> `update_term_meta( int $term_id, string $meta_key, mixed $meta_value, mixed $prev_value = '' )`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/

Comment: thanks I will try now and i also found something useful about $wpdb->update

Comment: ok. I think update_term_meta is better. Thank you very much. Tom J Nowell

Comment: it worked like charm thank you very much again. I had absolutely no idea how to fix this problem. Thanks sooo much. You are best